# What is the "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" HTTP header?

Tags: google-chrome, http, http-headers, upgrade-insecure-requests

I made a POST request to a HTTP (non-HTTPS) site, inspected the request in Chrome's Developer Tools, and found that it added its own header before sending it to the server:

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

After doing a search on `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests`, I can only find [information](http://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/) about the server sending [this](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/csp-upgrade-insecure-requests/) header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

This seems related, but still very different since in my case, the CLIENT is sending the header in the *Request*, whereas all the information I've found is concerning the SERVER sending the related header in a *Response*.

---

So why is Chrome (44.0.2403.130 m) adding `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests` to my request and what does it do?

---

## Update 2016-08-24:

This header has since been added as a [W3C Candidate Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-upgrade-insecure-requests-20151008/#preference) and is now officially recognized.

For those who just came across this question and are confused, the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32003517/2891365) by Simon East explains it well.

The `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1` header used to be `HTTPS: 1` [in the previous W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-upgrade-insecure-requests-20150424/#preference) and was renamed ***quietly*** by Chrome before the change became officially accepted.

(This question was asked during this transition when there were no official documentation on this header and Chrome was the only browser that sent this header.)

Comment: Firefox does it too.

Comment: Must be new; I do development on Firefox first and this header definitely wasn't sent from Firefox last year.

Answer (score 282, accepted):

**Short answer: it's closely related to the `Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests` response header, indicating that the browser supports it (and in fact prefers it).**

It took me 30mins of Googling, but I finally found it buried in the W3 spec.

The confusion comes because the header in the spec was `HTTPS: 1`, and this is how Chromium implemented it, but after this [broke lots of websites that were poorly coded](https://superuser.com/questions/943842/chrome-adds-weird-https1-header-to-all-requests) (particularly WordPress and WooCommerce) the Chromium team apologized:

> "I apologize for the breakage; I apparently underestimated the impact based on the feedback during dev and beta."
> — Mike West, in [Chrome Issue 501842](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501842#c43)

Their fix was to rename it to `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1`, and the spec has since been updated to match.

Anyway, here is the explanation from [**the W3 spec** (as it appeared at the time)](http://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/#preference)...

> The `HTTPS` HTTP request header field sends a signal to the server **expressing the client’s preference** for an encrypted and authenticated response, and that **it can successfully handle the upgrade-insecure-requests directive** in order to make that preference as seamless as possible to provide.
>
> ...
>
> When a server encounters this preference in an HTTP request’s headers, it SHOULD redirect the user to a potentially secure representation of the resource being requested.
>
> When a server encounters this preference in an HTTPS request’s headers, it SHOULD include a `Strict-Transport-Security` header in the response if the request’s host is HSTS-safe or conditionally HSTS-safe [RFC6797].

Comment: I fail to understand it. I'm `a.com` and redirect you to `b.com`, while providing this header to `b.com` and sending some information. If you're not under a secure channel to `b.com`, a sniffing-attack can happen already, because I've sent data to `b.com` alongside my request. Can you guide us to a simple scenario of how it makes connections more secure for users?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Under a very strict perspective it doesn't make anything more secure. If you have normal security requirements then you have to make sure you connect via HTTPS first and not rely on this. That being said, I would describe this in the context of the idea of "[Trust on First Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use)", which *does* help passively.

Comment: I see this more as client's desire than security tool. It's like "DNT" header, server could ignore it, but yet it expresses client's will.

Comment: My answer could actually be improved to properly explain how the client and server negotiate this. Feel free to suggest improvements if you'd like.

Answer (score 9):

This explains the whole thing:

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) upgrade-insecure-requests
>   directive instructs user agents to treat all of a site's insecure URLs
>   (those served over HTTP) as though they have been replaced with secure
>   URLs (those served over HTTPS). This directive is intended for web
>   sites with large numbers of insecure legacy URLs that need to be
>   rewritten.
>
> The upgrade-insecure-requests directive is evaluated before
>   block-all-mixed-content and if it is set, the latter is effectively a
>   no-op. It is recommended to set one directive or the other, but not
>   both.
>
> The upgrade-insecure-requests directive will not ensure that users
>   visiting your site via links on third-party sites will be upgraded to
>   HTTPS for the top-level navigation and thus does not replace the
>   Strict-Transport-Security (HSTS) header, which should still be set
>   with an appropriate max-age to ensure that users are not subject to
>   SSL stripping attacks.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests

Comment: What does it mean to "treat all of a site's insecure URLs as though they have been replaced with secure URLs"? Should the browser silently rewrite `http` to `https` in `href`s and `src`s, or should it happily navigate to `http` URIs on an `https` page even when such would be blocked by the browser's normal security? How much of this "treating" is visible to the user (in the address bar, HTML etc.)? This is extremely vague.

Comment: @IS4: URLs for non-navigational insecure resources (e.g. images) will be rewritten, before the request is made, meaning that no insecure requests will hit the network. Navigational links to third-party resources (e.g. hyperlinks), however, will not be upgraded to HTTPS.